# When I LEFT JOIN 2 table, how do I return 0 if the value is NULL?

Tags: sqlite, ionic2, ionic-native

I'm trying to set 0 to any null value in a LEFT JOIN, using coalesce() or ifnull(), in SQLite. 
I know this question have been asked a lot, however, I'm stuck.

```
BUDGET
amount category
2      food
2      book
2      movie

EXPENSE
amount category
2      food
2      book

EXPECTED RESULT
budsum budcat expsum
2      food   2
2      book   2
2      movie  0
```

This is the query that I've done.

```
SELECT SUM(budget.amount) AS budsum, budget.category AS budcat,
SUM(coalesce(expense.amount,0)) AS expsum 
FROM budget 
LEFT JOIN expense 
ON budcat=expense.category
GROUP BY budcat;

SELECT SUM(budget.amount) AS budsum, budget.category AS budcat,
SUM(coalesce(expense.amount,0)) AS expsum 
FROM budget 
LEFT JOIN expense 
ON budcat=expense.category
GROUP BY budcat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `coalesce` on the `sum` instead.

```
select SUM(budget.amount) as budsum,
    budget.category as budcat,
    coalesce(SUM(expense.amount), 0) as expsum
from budget
left join expense on budget.category = expense.category
group by budget.category;
```

Comment: i've tried that before. didn't work. for some context, I'm coding for Ionic2 app, using Cordova-sqlite-storage for the database

Comment: @AhmadZul - Didn't work how? Did it still produce nulls? Did it fail?

Comment: it didn't fail. just didn't return the 0 value